# Pass PHP variable to Json

Tags: php, json, request, postman

I've got the following code that seems to be not working in case I use PHP variable to define values. On the other hand, if I hard-code values it works fine.

```
$body->append('{
    "username": "$username",
    "password": "$password",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "$name",
        "surname": "$surname",
        "email": "$mail"
    }
}');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass variables inside strings in PHP you must use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`.

```
$foo = "bar";
echo 'Hello $foo'; // Outputs 'Hello $foo'
echo "Hello $foo"; // Outputs 'Hello bar'
```

The following code should work, it's the same but wrapped with `"` (instead of `'`) and escaped the original quotes with `\"`.

```
$body->append("{
    \"username\": \"$username\",
    \"password\": \"$password\",
    \"attributes\": {
        \"name\": \"$name\",
        \"surname\": \"$surname\",
        \"email\": \"$mail\"
    }
}");
```

However, it can get quite messy that way, instead you can use concatenation with `.` between strings and variables

```
'"username": "' . $username . '"
```

Or just use [DarkBee's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679882/10400050) which is a bit more elegant for your purpose.

Comment: You can't use single quotes in json

Comment: @TrueTiem my mistake, switched to escaped double quotes :)

Answer (score 5):

make an array of it and then [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it to pass it to your function

```
$data = [
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password,
    "attributes" => [
        "name"  => $name,
        "surname"=> $surname,
        "email" => $mail,
    ],
];
$body->append(json_encode($data));
```